# Call method in router view page from a component

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

Apologies first, im still getting the hang of Vuejs but I have a question about “best” approaching this problem.

I have the following structure:

- APP

  - Component (has 3 items, each item has a delete button)
  - Router-view (search page with 10 items)

Deleting an item in the component, needs to DESELECT the corresponding item from the list in the Router-view page (search). The Search page has a ‘deselectItem’ method in it. I need to call this method after the delete button has been clicked.

Possible solutions:

### Solution 1:

I realise that i can solve this issue by putting all the SEARCH PAGE items in VUEX however the items on the search page will not be accessed from any other components (just this one).

### Solution 2:

I have read about using $refs however i am not sure how this would work when I need to place the $refs on the search page as it is a router-view page and not a component.

### Solution 3:

Event bus. Would this be my only other viable option?

Are there are any best practises that I am missing here?

Thank you!

Comment: you will get much better response by including an [mcve] possibly on codepen

Comment: I would go with **vuex**, even if the **search page items** will be accessed from only one place. Also, if you use [vue devtools](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools), it's easy to see the vuex store and mutations there